# How to get the first column value of a selected row in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView

How do I get a value of a column for a given row.

I tried the following but it only gives the row number instead of the value:

```
int selRowIndex = ((GridViewRow)(((System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox)sender).Parent.Parent)).RowIndex;
```

Comment: Please clarify. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are looking for the contentnot the index

```
var cellText= ((GridViewRow)(((System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox)sender).Parent.Parent)).Cells[0].Text;
```

and then convert it to int

Comment: `Error 2 Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRow'`

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge. Take a look to my update now :)

Comment: Thanks. That worked great. Testing it out and will accept it when ready.

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge hope it works for you . if it's ok mark it as correct thx